# How do I output the vertical list into horizontal lists

Tags: java, output

```
public class NormalNumbers {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 1;

    while ((x >= 1) && (x <= 100)) {

      System.out.println("x = " + x);

      x = x + 1;

    }
  }
}
```

The current output is:

```
x = 1
x = 2
...
x = 100
```

I want to change the format to:

```
x=1 x=2 x=3 x=4 x=5
x=6 x=7 x=8 x=9 x=10
```

and so on.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: using loops. i want it like 1 2 3 4 5 and start again on the next line with 6 7 8 9 10

Comment: `for` statement looks better. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `println()`, which automatically inserts a newline character at the end of whatever you're printing, just use `print()` and add an extra space to pad your entries.

If you want to inject a newline after `5` entries specifically, you can do so with an empty `println()` and the modulus operator like so:

```
while ((x >= 1) && (x <= 100)) {
    System.out.print("x = " + x);
    if (x % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    x = x + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`System.out.println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String)) prints the text and adds a new line. Use [`System.out.print`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.String)) to print on the same line instead.

So it would be something like this:

```
System.out.print("x=" + x + " ");
```

To add a new line each 5 numbers, use:

```
// if x is multiple of 5, add a new line
if (x % 5 == 0) {
    System.out.println();
}
```

PD: You can use `x++` ([increment operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)) or `x += 1` (in the case you want to increase in more than one unit) instead of `x = x + 1`.

PD2 : You might want to use a tabulation (`\t`) instead of a space for separating your numbers. That way, numbers with two digits will have the same indentation than numbers with one digit.

```
System.out.print("x=" + x + "\t");
```

Answer (score 2):

Divide your counter by 5 using modulus division if there is no remainder then create a new line:

```
int x = 1;

while ((x >= 1) && (x <= 100))
{
    System.out.print("x = " + x + " ");
    if(x % 5 == 0)
    {
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
    x = x + 1;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `println` is next line, `print` is on the same line.
- `x % 5 == 0` checks that the x values is a multiple of 5 or not.

  ```
  int x = 1;

  while ((x >= 1) && (x <= 100)) {

      if (x % 5 == 0) {
          System.out.println("x="+x);
      } else {
          System.out.print("x=" +x+ " ");

      }

      x = x + 1;

  }
  ```

That gives you output as

```
x=1 x=2 x=3 x=4 x=5
x=6 x=7 x=8 x=9 x=10
x=11 x=12 x=13 x=14 x=15
x=16 x=17 x=18 x=19 x=20
-----
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your case the better way is using `for(;;)` statement:

```
for (int x = 1; x > 0 && x < 101;)
    System.out.print("x = " + x + (x++ % 5 == 0 ? "\n" : " "));
```

The ternary operator `x++ % 5 == 0 ? "\n" : " "` is responsible for the new line and increment the `x` variable.

Output:

```
x = 1 x = 2 x = 3 x = 4 x = 5
x = 6 x = 7 x = 8 x = 9 x = 10
...
x = 96 x = 97 x = 98 x = 99 x = 100
```